# $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n}{e}\right)^n$

Tags: calculus, limits

Could anyone please help me find limit?
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n}{e}\right)^n$$

Thank you

Comment: Please use the latex format to write your question

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3999343/edit) your question to [provide context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960), including what you have tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3673845/evaluating-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-frac1-frac1nnen)  answer your question? (and an [older one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2081033))

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Math.SE! To guide you properly, it would be very helpful to understand the context of what you are asking and what you tried already.

---

To get you started, note that since $f(x) = \ln x$ is a continuous function for $x>0$, you have
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} g(n)
 = \exp\left( \ln\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} g(n)\right)\right)
 = \exp\left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \ln(g(n))\right)
$$
and taking logarithm of the function you are taking the limit of will greatly simplify it.

Can you finish this now? If not, please update with details of what you tried and what is not working so we may guide you further.

Comment: Thank you. maybe later

Answer (score 0):

This limit is equivalent to
$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{\left(1 + x\right)^{\frac1x}}{e}\right)^{\frac1x} $$
$$ L = \lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{e^{\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}}}{e}\right)^{\frac1x} $$
$$ = \lim_{x\to 0} \left(e^{\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}-1} \right)^{\frac1x}$$
$$ = \lim_{x\to 0} \left(e^{1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3} +\cdots -1} \right)^{\frac1x} $$
$$ = \lim_{x\to 0} \left(e^{-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3} +\cdots} \right)^{\frac1x} $$
$$ = \lim_{x\to 0} \left(e^{-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{3} +\cdots } \right) $$
$$ = e^{-\frac12} $$
$$ \boxed{ \therefore \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n}{e}\right)^n = \lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{\left(1 + x\right)^{\frac1x}}{e}\right)^{\frac1x} = \color{red}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{e}}}}$$

Comment: Can you please explain why ln(1+x)x−1 transform to 1−x2+x23+⋯−1

Comment: @AllMywork It's the Taylor expansion for $\ln(1+x)$ $$\ln(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} \cdots \text{if} -1 < x \leq 1$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n}{e}\right)^n$$

Let $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n}{e}=1+t\implies t= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n-e}{e}$

$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{n\frac{\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n-e}{e}}$$

The series expansion of $\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ when $n\to\infty$ is $e-\frac{e}{2n}+O(n^2)$

$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{n\frac{\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n-e}{e}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{n\frac{-e}{2ne}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt e}$$

The reason for introducing $t$ is to convert the function to the form $\lim_{f\to\infty}(1+f)^{1/f}$